# isRemoveOnCompletion not work after the animation is completed

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, core-graphics, core-animation

I want my moonImageView to keep its last size/dimension after the animation ended; image gets bigger by 1.25 time, but adding `isRemoveOnCompletion = false` did not help. The size of image returned back after the animation ended.
How may I fix this? Did I misuse it?

```
//setup
    moonImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    moonImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    moonImageView.addTapGesture(tapNumber: 1, target: self, action: #selector(moonClick))

//layout
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        moonImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        moonImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        moonImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
        moonImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
    ])

//func
@objc private func moonClick() {
    let moonAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    moonAnimation.fromValue = 1
    moonAnimation.toValue = 1.25
    moonAnimation.duration = 0.25
    moonAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    
    moonImageView.layer.add(moonAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the whole `isRemovedOnCompletion` thing; that's just a canard. Of course the animation should be removed on completion; it's over. The problem is simply that you forgot to the layer's *actual* transform to the `toValue`. (The animation is just sort of a visual illusion and has no effect on the layer's actual transform.)

```
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
moonImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.25, 1.25, 1)
```

Comment: wait @matt where do I add this line of code? After the animation or prior? Does not adding this line of code making the image grow without animation? Thanks

Comment: Try it and see what happens.